# Text diff using library in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, diff

I want to use a text diff in jsFiddle/or plunker from this example,
currenlty this is not working , what Im doing wrong?

this is the lib that I need to use
https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff

I need the following webExample

https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/examples/web_example.html

and this is what I've tried,without success.

https://jsfiddle.net/bvwbawLL/

```
<pre id="display"></pre>
<script src="github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff"></script>
<script>
var one = 'beep boop';
var other = 'beep boob blah';

var diff = JsDiff.diffChars(one, other);
var display = document.getElementById('display');

diff.forEach(function(part){
  // green for additions, red for deletions
  // grey for common parts
  var color = part.added ? 'green' :
    part.removed ? 'red' : 'grey';
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.color = color;
  span.appendChild(document
    .createTextNode(part.value));
  display.appendChild(span);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're (wrongly) linking to the project home page in your <script> tag (wrongly because you need to specify `https://` - otherwise `github.com/...` is seen as a 'subdirectory' below jsfiddle.net). You'll need to download a [release](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/releases) or, simpler, link to the JS file: `http://kpdecker.github.io/jsdiff/diff.js`. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvwbawLL/1/).

Comment: @Kenney HI Kenny this is the answer so put it as answer, i've two question 1. how did you find the right link? 2. how does JsDiff.diffChars(one, other);  doesnt failed  from where jsDiff get the value? Thanks you!

Comment: It's as easy as *"view source"* in demo page, copying link to the js file there ... working demo https://jsfiddle.net/bvwbawLL/2/ You can't get script from home page of a repo

Comment: I looked at the browser console (F12), and saw 2 errors: `"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://fiddle.jshell.net/bvwbawLL/show/github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff"` (that told me the `https://` was missing), and `ReferenceError: JsDiff is not defined`. I went to the page, couldn't find a distribution `.js`, then googled around (`kpdecker jsdiff cdn`) and I saw the ["DIff Chars" github.io result](http://kpdecker.github.io/jsdiff/). Went there, and found the location of the js (F12) again. But you should probably use the js from a release (see link in other comment).

Comment: @Kenney - Thanks please add this description as answer and I can close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the indispensable browser console (usually F12), there's these errors:

```
NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://fiddle.jshell.net/bvwbawLL/show/github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff

ReferenceError: JsDiff is not defined
   var diff = JsDiff.diffChars(one, other);
```

This is caused by:

```
<script src="github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff"></script>
```

which has 2 issues:

- it is missing the protocol part of the URL: `https://` in this case. Leaving it out makes it a link relative to the page.
- the link points to the project page, not a JavaScript file.

Now, after some searching I found an online version of the `diff.js` on the page http://kpdecker.github.io/jsdiff/ (use F12 to find the script).

However, this is not listed as the resource to use. I haven't found a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) hosting it either. So, for a little fiddle you could use that file - but it may disappear without notice! For a production site, you better [download a release](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/releases) and host the script file yourself.